# What alternatives are there for " readlink -e"

Tags: macos, makefile, readlink

I use a makefile which in order to create a library uses a .pc file which looks like this

```
current_path=`readlink -e .`
cat > lib/libmy.pc << EOM
prefix=$current_path
includedir=\${prefix}/inc
libdir=\${prefix}/lib

Name: my
Description: My library
Version: 1.0
Cflags: -I\${includedir}
Libs: -L\${libdir} -lmy
Libs.private: -lm
EOM
```

The problem is that on mac the -e flag doesn't work (even I installed coreutils). I there a method to replace the flag?

Comment: GNU make has `$(realpath .)`

Comment: Thank you, how should I include it into the script: "current_path=$(realpath .)"?

Comment: `current_path:=$(realpath .)` is better as realpath may actually read the disk drive.

Comment: This is not `Makefile` code; how does `make` invoke this? Can you add an argument to the invocation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most portable way I could find:

```
current_path=`python -c "import os; print(os.path.abspath('${MY_AWESOME_PATH}'))"`
```

in your case:

```
current_path=`python -c "import os; print(os.path.abspath('.'))"`
```