# Print program path and its symlink using which

Tags: bash, unix, ls

Whenever I use `which` I do this: `$ which -a npm`

Which results in: `/usr/local/bin/npm`

Then to find the real path, I run:
`ls -l /usr/local/bin/npm`

I would like a fast way of doing this. The best I have come up with is defining a function:

```
which(){
  /usr/bin/which -a "$@" | xargs ls -l | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f 9-
}
```

Now it has a nice output of: `/usr/local/bin/npm -> ../lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js`

Is there a better way to do this? I don't like using cut like this.

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/57195470/10678955

Answer (score 0):

This won't print the `->` output `ls -l` does, but it will resolve symlinks:

```
which() {
    command which -a "$@" | xargs -d '\n' readlink -m
}
```

If you want the `->` output but want to do it more robustly, you could mimic `ls -l` with:

```
which() {
    command which -a "$@" | while IFS= read -r file; do
        if [[ -L $file ]]; then
            echo "$file -> $(readlink -m "$file")"
        else
            echo "$file"
        fi
    done
}
```

> What does `command` do?

`command` suppresses function lookup and runs the built-in `which` command as if `which()` weren't defined. This way you don't have to hardcode `/usr/bin/which`.

Comment: I don't have -d or -m for readlink. I'm on macOS. What does `command` do?

Answer (score 0):

`awk`: if first character is "l" (link), print fields 9,10,11; else only 9.

```
[ranga@garuda ~]$ ls -l $(which -a firefox)|awk '{print $1 ~ /^l/ ? $9 $10 $11 : $9 }'
/usr/bin/firefox->/usr/lib64/firefox/firefox
```

- `$1` is the first field
- `$1 ~ /^l/ ?` tests whether the first field matches the pattern `^l` (first character is "l")
- if the test passes, `print` receives `$9 $10 $11`; else, only `$9`.

`sed` : remove first 8 non-space and space character bunches.

```
[ranga@garuda ~]$ ls -l $(which firefox) | sed 's/^\([^ ]*[ ]*\)\{8\}//'
/usr/bin/firefox -> /usr/lib/firefox/firefox
```

- `[ ]*` matches a bunch of contiguous spaces
- `[^ ]*` matches a contiguous bunch of non-space characters
- the grouping `\([^ ]*[ ]*\)` matches a text with one non-space bunch and one space bunch (in that order).
- `\{8\}` matches 8 contiguous instances of this combination. `^` at the beginning pins the match to the beginning of the line.
- `'s/^\([^ ]*[ ]*\)\{8\}//'` replaces a match with empty text - effectively removing it.

seems to work so long as you aren't running "which" on an alias.

these commands are not presented inside a function but can be used in one (which you already know how to).

Comment: Well now I have which as a function. Ha, I have no idea what's going on in that awk command.